# Tranformation of any input video file to mxf is failing

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have recently upgraded ffmpeg 2.8.1 to 4.3.1. Post upgradation, I see that for transformation of any input video file format to mxf is failing (while with older version it works fine).

Command used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f mxf_d10 -r 29.97 -s 720x512 -b:v 30000k -g 12 -qscale 15 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 4 -ar 48000 -vol 256 -strict experimental VIDEO1-173888047.mxf
```

Error:

> [mxf_d10 @ 000000e368e07380] track 0: frame size does not match index unit size,
> 18253 != 125125
> av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Looks like [#8077: NTSC IMX encoding in MXF not possible](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8077).

Comment: Hi @llogan, thanks for your reply. I am able to execute the command if I remove -f  mxf_d10. Can you help me with the scenario here? Is it still performing NTSC IMX encoding?

Comment: Sorry, but I that's not a format I use, so I don't know.

Comment: There is also  [#8582 Remuxing of Panasonic P2 MXF file fails (regression)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8582) which gives the same "frame size does not match index unit size, ... av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted" error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty curiuos that this issue is still there, even when using the very recent ffmpeg 5.0 of year 2022.

The following command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4  -c:v mpeg2video -top 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p -g 1  -b:v 50M  -minrate 50M  -maxrate 50M  -b:v 50M  -bufsize 2M   -rc_init_occupancy 2M -c:a pcm_s16le -f mxf_d10 out.mxf
```

gives the error

```
[mxf_d10 @ 0xcfbe840] track 0: frame size does not match index unit size, 59024 != 25000083x
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
[mxf_d10 @ 0xcfbe840] Received non-video packet before header has been written
Error writing trailer of pezza.mxf: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I was able to solve by adding these additional two parameters:

```
-bufsize 2M   -rc_init_occupancy 2M
```

Then the overall command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4  -c:v mpeg2video -top 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p -g 1  -b:v 50M  -minrate 50M  -maxrate 50M  -b:v 50M  -bufsize 2M   -rc_init_occupancy 2M -c:a pcm_s16le -f mxf_d10 out.mxf
```

produces a fully compliant MXF D10

I actually dont't understand well what  rc_init_occupancy does but works.
Many thanks and happy coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).